# How to achieve similar 2D "overflow-hidden" effect in 3D react-three-fiber?

Tags: canvas, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, clipping

I am trying to similar 2D effect of overflow-hidden but in 3D model with reference to this amazing [kprverse website](https://kprverse.com/). I tried using clipping plane but it does not produce the same effect.

Below is original 3D model before clipping

[image: original model]

After Clipping

[image: clipped model]

Ideally, the result should show model between the red lines and overflow should be hidden. But, I could not achieve it with clipping planes.

[image: ideally clipped model]

is there any better way to achieve the similar 2D "overflow-hidden" effect?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-cache-8j9iji?file=/src/App.js:0-2081

Following is my codes.

```
 import * as THREE from "three";
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls, ScrollControls } from "@react-three/drei";

import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";

export const FLOOR_HEIGHT = 2.3;
export const NB_FLOORS = 3;

export default function TestingClipping(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("./models/WawaOffice.glb");
  const planes = useRef([
    new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0, 0), 1),
    new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0), 1)
  ]);
  return (
    <Canvas
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
      gl={{ localClippingEnabled: true }}
    >
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} enableDamping={false} />
      <ScrollControls pages={3} damping={0.25}>
        <group scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
          <group
            {...props}
            dispose={null}
            position={[0.5, -1, -1]}
            rotation={[0, -Math.PI / 3, 0]}
            style={{ transform: "scale(0.1)" }}
          >
            <mesh geometry={nodes["01_office"].geometry}>
              <meshStandardMaterial
                {...materials["01"]}
                clippingPlanes={planes.current}
              />
            </mesh>
            <group position={[0, 2.11, -2.23]}>
              <group>
                <mesh geometry={nodes["02_library"].geometry}>
                  <meshStandardMaterial
                    {...materials["02"]}
                    clippingPlanes={planes.current}
                  />
                </mesh>
              </group>
            </group>
            <group position={[-1.97, 4.23, -2.2]}>
              <group>
                <mesh geometry={nodes["03_attic"].geometry}>
                  <meshStandardMaterial
                    {...materials["03"]}
                    clippingPlanes={planes.current}
                  />
                </mesh>
              </group>
            </group>
          </group>
        </group>
      </ScrollControls>
    </Canvas>
  );
}

// useGLTF.preload("./models/WawaOffice.glb");
```

Comment: I've never played with clipping planes but from what I see you should orient your planes to be perpendicular to the camera so no perspective is visible. Or switch to an orthographic camera

Comment: you can also check drei component Mask : https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#mask

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to [Remi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9670819/remi), I found the solution with drei-mask.

https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#mask

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).